# Run Tests Not Working

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'm in Visual Studio 2012 and I can run all tests, but if I try to run a single test within a class, or even all tests within a single class (by either clicking, or using Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T) nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "clicking" do you mean right click on class name and them click "Run tests"? Do you use Visual Studio unit testing or tools such as NUnit? Can you check that your shortcut is not attributed to another action.

Comment: I'm not using anything specific.... just the base installation of whatever comes with Visual Studio.  I'm right clicking the [TestMethod] above the method.  This worked fine for me and then I did an SVN checkout of the project in a fresh directory and it stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  You need to add a Debug Configuration to your project from the Build -> Configurations menu.  For some reason it needs to be called Debug.